Java uses the system libraries of Linux
I am encountering the following issue:
When using Java 8 + Spring, I have the following code:
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        SecurityUtilsBase.extractNativeLibraries("/usr/lib");
    }
}

and
@PostMapping("/decrypt")
public String decrypt(@RequestParam String value) {
    try {
        TestCrypt crypt = new TestCrypt(); 
        return crypt.cypher_Damo_Decrypt_B64(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

The library loading in TestCrypt:
static {
    try {
        System.out.println("Before System.loadLibrary..");
        System.loadLibrary("testcryptjni");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var1) {
        System.out.println("libmascryptjni.so load error " + var1);
    }
}

In this case, the controller doesn’t work at all, and the program stops immediately without any error message.
Stop app image
When I modify the main method and call it once before, like this:
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        SecurityUtilsBase.extractNativeLibraries("/usr/lib");
        TestCrypt crypt = new TestCrypt();
        System.out.println(crypt.cypher_Damo_Decrypt_B64("0hKybskMef8voU8QHxQhww=="));
    }
}

The controller then works normally. I suspect this is related to Java’s resource cleanup mechanism.
In Java 11, there is no way for this library to work. Why is that?
I tried to enable JNI logging, but it didn't work
JNI log

I would say that the SecurityUtilsBase.extractNativeLibraries("/usr/lib"); should be executed before the SpringApplication.run else you run the risk of the library being attempted to be loaded before the unpacking has been done leading to issues. JNI debugging is a real pain, do you really need to use this library is there no java based variant you can use? You can add -Xcheck:jni and -verbose:jni to your commandline when starting the app to get some more information from JNI.

That section only transfers the libraries from the resources into the /usr/lib of the Docker container. I just tried changing those two lines back, and the error still occurs

What are the file names of the libraries that are extracted?

What do you mean with resources directory? JNI needs them in a specific location (or locations) if the files aren't there it will fail to load them. I would also suggest to re-read my comment and enable debugging for JNI inside your container, else it is shooting in the dark and hope to hit something.

I tried to enable JNI logging, but it didn't work, Pic on end post

Don't use images for text information, like the command line outputs.
